# Log in through windows network and mount home via samba

Tags: networking, mount, login, samba

I'm a teacher in high school and I would like my pupils use Linux instead of the old and broken Windows.

Here is the description of the current network:

- the pupils log on Windows session through a Windows network. Once logged, they can store their contents in a folder on a drive named `H:`. For example, the folder of the pupils `Foo` in the class `Bar` is `H:\\class_bar\foo\` . The pupils can also read the folder `H:\\calss_bar\_work`, which is filled by the teachers.
- the teachers has RW access on all `H:`.
- I don't think I could modify the server ("What!! You want install Linux!?? But it's too complicated for our pupils!! Windows is quite enough!"...). Hopefully, I can discreetly install what I want on the computers in my class room :D.

I would like that the log on the computer under Linux simulate a log on a computer under Windows. I mean:

- the pupils and the teachers log with the same id's than in the Windows case,
- `H:\\class_bar\foo\` is mount on `/home/foo` (or at least on `/home/foo/network/`, I've read that could be difficult).

What is the simplest way to achieve these goals (there is not a lot of computers in my class room, I can manually repeat the install operations for all of them)? I'm not very familiar with network and *user login process*, what documentation/tutorials would you advise me to read?